# Disable UITextField left to right animation when setting NSTextAlignmentRight

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

For some reason, when setting the text alignment in a UITextField to NSTextAlignmentRight, text slides left to right when the text field is displayed.  This annoys me greatly.

Does anyone know how to disable this animation?  The UITextField is displayed in a UIAlertView, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Did u found some solution for this case?